How can a patent title be used to limit the scope when the title doesn't form a complete sentence or thought?
Let's take the following patent title:
Parallel Content Recommending Process System and Method

If this is a title, what of it can be used to interpret and therefore limit the scope?
Just from the title, we know only that the invention relates to perhaps computer generated recommendation of some content.
Adding the qualifier "parallel" doesn't seem at all to make it any less ambiguous.
